# How to track regions by line and character from a sequence of diffs (preferably in Unified Diff Format)

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, diff, jgit

I am analyzing a sequence of diffs in chronological order from a `.git` repository. I would like to create contiguous code block regions from these diffs that will represent all of the changes for the repository. Instead of reinventing the wheel, I wonder if there is a library that will process the diffs into regions. Details are at the end on how I used JGit to process the `.git` repository to get these diffs.

Each contiguous code block region can be represented as a `start line`, `end line`, `start offset`, and `end offset`. For example, if I have the following diff (in Unified Diff Format):

```
    @@ -35,4 +35,5 @@
    @Override
    public Set<V> getVertices()
    {
+       throw new RuntimeException("Method not implemented.");
    }
```

I can process it into the following region, represented as [`startOffset`, `endOffset`), [`startLine`, `endLine`):

```
[0, 58), [38, 39)
```

By convention, the `endOffset` and `endLine` are exclusive. To further demonstrate, I am looking for a library that will expand, contract, and merge these regions as I process more diffs. If I continue to process the following diff:

```
    @@ -35,5 +35,6 @@
    @Override
    public Set<V> getVertices()
    {
+       // New line with a comment.
        throw new RuntimeException("Method not implemented.");
    }
```

I will get region `[0, 31), [38, 39)`, which overlaps and merges with our existing region, to create the resulting region:

```
[0, 58), [38, 40)
```

I am rolling my own implementation in Java, but it is rather cumbersome. If a library exists where I can feed it diffs and it outputs the regions, it would be ideal. Any suggestions for libraries, useful tools, or relevant advice would be greatly appreciated.

I am developing these regions for an Eclipse plug-in, and the diffs have been generated using the JGit library.

**Purpose and background**

I basically need to know the current state of the codebase changes, represented as regions, after every commit. The commits are all fine-grained commits (often just a character or a line change). I am using JGit to process a `.git` repository, as shown below. I ultimately end up with a [DiffEntry](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/diff/DiffEntry.html) object, but nothing in the JGit API seems to provide the functionality that I seek to build the regions.

To get the commits in chronological order, I did the following:

```
public static List<RevCommit> getCommits(Git git) throws NoHeadException, GitAPIException
{
    List<RevCommit> commits = new ArrayList<>();
    for (RevCommit commit: log(git))
        commits.add(commit);
    Collections.reverse(commits);
    return commits;
}
```

With the commits above, I processed each contiguous pair of commits to get all of the diffs:

```
    for (int a = 0; a < commits.size() - 1; a++)// chronological order traversal.
    {
        // Compare each consecutive pairs of commits.
        RevCommit parentCommit = commits.get(a); // parent is the older commit (chronological
        // order traversal).
        RevCommit currentCommit = commits.get(a + 1);

        RevTree currentTree = currentCommit.getTree();
        RevTree parentTree = parentCommit.getTree();
        List<DiffEntry> diffs = GitOperations.getDiffEntries(git_, parentTree, currentTree);
        // A DiffEntry is 'A value class representing a change to a file' therefore for each
        // diff entry you have a file.
        // Assuming "diffs" has length 1 because we are assuming only 1 diff per commit.
        for (DiffEntry diff: diffs)
        {
            // Get the string representation of each diff and process the string to create the regions...
```

Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Unified Diff Format is not specific to Git, so I'm not sure the [tag:git] and [tag:jgit] tags are warranted, here. I'm not sure where you get the start and end offsets from... What does your current implementation consist in? `sed`/`awk`?

Comment: The start and end offsets are taken from the content of the string representing the changed line (ie `throw new RuntimeException("Method not implemented.");` and `// New line with a comment.`). Thus, I am parsing the UDF output, as a string, in Java to create my regions. I don't know how else to get the offset information. Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Just to clarify: You only get the text as input or are you in control of the code that creates the text (and could change it to instead produce something else)? It would help if you took a step back to explain what you're trying to achieve, maybe there is another way to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the OP is updated with some background info and code. Let me know if I missed anything.